# $.get doesn’t work until the code is executed another time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my main page I've a select element populated from a database as this:

```
<select id="report" class="selectpicker input-sm">
    <option value=''>Choose a date</option>
    <?php foreach($this->report as $report) {?>
        <option><?php echo $report->timepoint_name;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

I want that when I select an option, the text of that option will be add to my session variables, and I thought to use Ajax for this. In the same file I add this `javascript` code:

```
$('#report').on('change', function() {
    var report = $('#report').find(':selected').text();
    $.get("ajax.php", {'rep':report}, function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

When I logout from my application I destroy the session using php function `destroy_session()`, now login the first time the file `ajax.php` is not executed, I must run a second time the code to execute the php code in `ajax.php`.

I tried my source code with firebug, the ajax request was made and the console shows this line:

```
GET http://localhost/myproject/news_update/ajax.php?rep=1+Aug+2010+to+31+Jul+2011  302 Found 5ms
```

What is this error?

Comment: Because you didn't change the dropdown. Or because you didn't set no-cache headers on the ajax.php. And why did you say $.get in the question title when you're using $.post?

Comment: Certainly I changed the dropdown, how I can test then! but what you mean by no-cache headers? sorry for the mistake (I used $.get)

Comment: You can run into the issue (in IE especially) of subsequent Ajax requests not actually hitting the server but pulling from the cache if you don't set no-cache headers on the PHP that responds to the Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that your browser is not cacheing the response and actually making the ajax call with the following snippet:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Then, please understand the `.change` will not fire right away, it only fires if you interact with that select element AND change the value. If you wish it to fire right away you can do so like so:

```
$('#report').on('change', function() {
    var report = $('#report').find(':selected').text();
    $.get("ajax.php", {'rep':report}, function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}).trigger('change'); // trigger change event right away
```

Comment: I've the same problem!

Comment: Can you describe the steps to reproduce in greater detail? Also try it with firebug open and see if the ajax request is being made.

Comment: Yeah, firebug it's very nice tool, thanks I fixed the error. The location of my `ajax.php` is wrong when I login for the first time.